# Why data not displaying in the react-bootstrap-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a raw data in the react-bootstrap-table. The data which i am passing as property in the bootstrap table is displaying properly in the console but it is not displaying in the table respected rows.

*The function from which i am getting records.*

```
displayRecords = () => {
    var listAllRecords = this.props.data
    return (
    listAllRecords.map((listRecord,index) => {
        console.log(listRecord)
        listRecord.subData.map((singleData,index) => {
            console.log('singleData:' +index,singleData)
            return singleData.name
        })
    }) )
}
```

*Bootstrap table in which i want dislpay those records.*

```
<BootstrapTable ref='table' data={this.props.data}>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='records' dataFormat={this.displayRecords}>Record</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

*Result of `console.log(listRecord)`*

```
Table Row1: { 
subData: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, name: "data1"}
1: {id: 2, name: "data2"}
id: 2
image: null
name: "John"
}
Table Row2:{ 
subData: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, name: "data1"}
1: {id: 2, name: "data2"}
2: {id: 3, name: "data3"}
id: 3
image: null
name: "Doe"
}
```

*console log of singleData*

```
singleData: 0 {id: 2, name: "data"}
singleData: 1 {id: 3, name: "data1"}

singleData: 0 {id: 2, name: "data"}
singleData: 1 {id: 3, name: "data1"}

singleData: 0 {id: 2, name: "data"}
singleData: 1 {id: 3, name: "data1"}
singleData: 2 {id: 4, name: "data1"}
```

P.S: There are three rows records.

So, i want to display records in the table rows as the respected row wise like in the first row it should be display `"data1, data2"` and in the second row it shoud be display `"data1,data2,data3"`

Comment: you are not returning anything from `displayRecords` function.

Comment: @Thinker: i have returned the name filed but i forgot to copy it here. But it does not return any value.

Comment: add `return` before `listAllRecords.map((listRecord,index)`

Comment: @Thinker: Not displaying the actual records... But it displaying like this: <div>,</div>

Answer (score 1):

Try this lines of code:-
1. Make a state:-

```
this.state = {
     dataList:[]
}
```

2. Add this in render() function:-

```
<BootstrapTable data={dataList}>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

3. Modify displayRecords() method :-

```
displayRecords = () => {
        var listAllRecords = this.props.data
        listAllRecords.map((listRecord,index) => {
            console.log(listRecord)
            this.setState({
                 dataList: listRecord
            })
            listRecord.subData.map((singleData,index) => {
                console.log(singleData)            
                singleData.name
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Where can i return my records ? :)

Comment: return singleData.name; in displayRecords() method.

Comment: I need to display records in a particular column... so `dataFormat` is there to display records.

Comment: And yes please remember that to not use setState in the `array.map()` function.